# ¿Por qué no se aplica los colores a mi div con los mediaqueries?

Tags: mediaqueries

Quiero que cambie de color según el tamaño de la pantalla, pero si escoge el color de los 900 no escoge el de 1200.

¿Qué está mal?

```
.caja
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color:  #FF0000;
transition-duration: 3s;

}

@media  only screen and (max-width:900px){
  .caja{
    transform: scalex(2);
background-color:  #FF0000;
  }

 }

@media  only screen and (max-width:1200px){
  .caja {
    background-color: #08088A;
  }

}

@media  only screen and (min-width:1201px){
 .caja {
   background-color: #DEF800;
 }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor tu problema? Según veo el color por defecto es el mismo que el de 900px, por lo tanto puede ser que ningún meda query sea respetado

Comment: El problema es que no me respeta lo smediaqueries aun quitando el color del de 900px:

Comment: Osea que si me lee un mediaquerie de 900 no me lee el de 1200 y viceversa

Comment: si quito el de 900  se supone q debe agarrar el color del 900

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que lea los dos al mismo tiempo? eso no se puede, porque se esta cambiando el mismo valor, en este caso el background-color

Comment: si entonces en ese caso que se debe hacer , pense que se podia estando en 900px y 1200px porque son medidas distintas

Comment: @Amarisu revisa mi respuesta mas abajo :) Saludos!!

Comment: entonces estas mal entendiendo el concepto de las media queries. Estas sirven para medir la resolución en pixeles del navegador, en este caso el width, dependiendo el tamaño del navegador serán las propiedades que se tomarán para aplicarse en los estilos de los elementos de tu html. Obviamente el navegador solo tiene un ancho

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te sirva :)

```css
.caja
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color:  #FF0000;
transition-duration: 3s;

}

@media  only screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width: 1199px){
  .caja{
    transform: scalex(2);
    background-color:  #FF0000;
    width: 500px;
  }

 }

@media  only screen and (min-width:1200px){
  .caja {
    background-color: #08088A;
    width: 800px;
  }

}

@media  only screen and (min-width:1201px){
 .caja {
   background-color: #DEF800;
 }

}

}
```

```html
<div class="caja"></div
```

Comment: Se debe comentar que realiza y que puede ayudar a solucionar, Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto debe ser usar min-width cuando trabajas con múltiples opciones dado que max-width el motor de renderizado sobrescribe a la mayor opción valida.

```css
.caja {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:500px) {
    .caja {
        /*transform: scalex(2);*/
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:900px) {
    .caja {
        background-color: #08088A;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
    .caja {
        background-color: #DEF800;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
</div>
```